# Slow Motion Water Physics Settings

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

so does anyone know some settings to get slow motion fluid in Blender?
Starting from a basic scene and tweaking settings to get slow motion fluid. Any answers are helpful and thank you for your time!

Comment: Render it out as a 60fps animation and slow it to 30fps in post

Answer (score 4):

Select your domain object, go to the *physics*->*Fluid* tab, and change the *speed* value to something lower than 1, for example to 0.5 if you want the simulation to have half the normal speed.

[image]